# Find an alternating (letter or number) + letter pattern in a file name

Tags: python, regex

From the following list of filenames I am trying to retrieve the highlighted parts:

- something something **Ah6d8c**.txt
- something **Qd6h7s**.txt
- something**AcKhJs**something.txt
- **7h6c8c** something.txt

The pattern is:

- 6 characters long
- starts with 2-9 or A K Q J T, both lower and uppercase
- the second character is always h s c d, both lower and uppercase
- the third and fourth match the first and second
- same for the fifth and sixth

```py
import os
import re

root = "C:/root"
data = dict()

re_pattern = "[a-zA-Z|2-9][h|s|c|d][a-zA-Z|2-9][h|s|c|d][a-zA-Z|2-9][h|s|c|d]"

for folder in os.listdir(root):
    data[folder] = dict()
    for item in os.listdir(f"{root}/{folder}"):
        board_id = re.findall(item, re_pattern)
        print(board_id)
        data[folder][item] = f"{root}/{folder}/{item}"
```

I thought my regex would work but it finds an empty list. Is my regex or my code wrong? The goal is to have the board_id be the dictionary key and the value the entire path.

**EDIT**
Improved pattern looks like:

```py
import os
import re

root = "C:/root"
data = dict()

re_pattern = "(?i)(?:[2-9AJKQT][hscd]){3}"

for folder in os.listdir(root):
    data[folder] = dict()
    for item in os.listdir(f"{root}/{folder}"):
        board_id = re.search(item, re_pattern)
        print(f"{item} :: {board_id}")
        data[folder][item] = f"{root}/{folder}/{item}"
```

Results are still not right, must be in the code instead:

- As6d5d BTN 2.5x vs BB.txt :: None
- SRP 3x 5h6d3c.txt :: None

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in a [quantified](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
(?i)(?:[2-9AJKQT][hscd]){3}
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jEyIbo/2) or [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##XY4xC8IwFIT3/IpsSUA7WGirIKVrOxXcagdJoi/QpuXlDYr422NBsOh29x3H3fwgmHwaoxvnCYmjZSwQ8iMXYRotgfM3vqoKMlPohO509ittTQZ5@KOVbqAOX/tJc8h0ofkPFYyhDcsi2uTqvLkMg0QhS6dkeeh2231VN@2p7yBo06tn@hIbvlxUbEbnSS5dFeMb)

For *caseless* matching use `(?i)` [flag](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) or `re.IGNORECASE`.

---

Taking a closer look at your code, further be aware of [order, arguments are passed in `re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
 re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

Another idea for future, it might further be, to consider generally using [raw string notation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for regex patterns but this is not an issue with your current pattern.

Comment: Should be case-insensitive, so add `(?i)` to the beginning.

Comment: @ekhumoroyes yea, you use the inline flag in beginning or `re.IGNORECASE`

Comment: @ekhumoro oops, I thought you are the OP :) Thanks also toolic for the advice. I've overlooked the insensitive part when posting my answer!

Comment: Hey, the pattern does exactly what it needs to do in regex101. I think it must be in my code. If I use re.search I get an empty list back, if I use re.findall I get None back.

```re_pattern = "(?i)(?:[2-9AJKQT][hscd]){3}"

        board_id = re.search(item, re_pattern)
        print(f"{item} :: {board_id}")
```

As6d5d BTN 2.5x vs BB.txt :: None
SRP 3x 5h6d3c.txt :: None